# how to insert the current url of the page in the database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            ip.patientname = fc["patientname"];
            ip.patientmail = fc["patientmail"];
            ip.patientcountry = fc["patientcountry"];
            ip.patientquery = fc["patientquery"];
            ip.SecurityCode = fc["SecurityCode"];

            string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;




            dblayer.Add_data_pharma(ip);
            TempData["msg"] = "Inserted";

        }
        else
        {
            TempData["msg"] = "Not Inserted";
        }


        ModelState.Clear();
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
    }
```

**string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;**

I want to know how to insert url name in the database using **Request.Url.AbsoluteUri** or any method.

```
public void Add_data_pharma(insert_askpharma_mar212019 ip)
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert_askpharma", con);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pharmaid", ip.pharmaid);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientname", ip.patientname);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientmail", ip.patientmail);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientcountry", ip.patientcountry);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientquery", ip.patientquery);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecurityCode", ip.SecurityCode);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@urlname", string.Empty);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ipaddress", string.Empty);
            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

I want to insewrt the current page url in the database using mvc

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <h3 style="color:#669900">Personal Information</h3>
                                               @using (Html.BeginForm("AskOurPharmacist", "Basic", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "kycFormTab5" }))
                                             {
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="email">Name*</label>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="patientname" name="patientname">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="pwd">Phone*</label>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="email">Email*</label>
                                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="patientmail" name="patientmail">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">

                                                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="patientcountry" name="patientcountry">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">

                                                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="patientquery" name="patientquery">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">

                                                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="SecurityCode" name="SecurityCode">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="urlname" name="urlname">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Email me When in Stock</button>
                                             }
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div class="rbox">
                                                    <h4 class=" text-center"><strong>Why shop with Us?</strong></h4>
                                                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                        <li><i class="fa fa-heart">&nbsp;</i>Trusted for Quality and Price</li>
                                                        <li><i class="fa fa-heart">&nbsp;</i>80-90% Savings - Lowest Prices</li>
                                                        <li><i class="fa fa-heart">&nbsp;</i>Free Shipping WorldWide*</li>
                                                        <li><i class="fa fa-heart">&nbsp;</i>360° Round View of Products</li>
                                                        <li><i class="fa fa-heart">&nbsp;</i>No Hidden Cost</li>
                                                        <li><i class="fa fa-heart">&nbsp;</i>Saving Rewards, Referral Discounts</li>
                                                        <li><i class="fa fa-heart">&nbsp;</i>Quality-Assured Medications</li>
                                                        <li class="text-right">*T&C Apply</li>
</ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

This is my view ,in one mehod i have inserted two forms in this form only i want to insert the url in the database all are in the same table

[this is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efwUg.png)

Comment: how to pass the  string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;  in the datbase

Comment: Request.Url.AbsoluteUri is string , save it in a new column what is your problem exactly ?

Comment: I want to insert the current page url in the database when the form submitted please help me ,my code is above and databse is there

Comment: ip.URL= Request.Url.AbsoluteUri; ?????????

Comment: it is not working\

Comment: What did you mean in not working ? post more details if you still help from the community.

Comment: Now you can understand it

Comment: Please help me for doing this

Comment: Ok, go to stored procedure insert_askpharma there you need to add new parameter and then in c# you need to pass it.

Comment: i have passed the urlname in stored procedure already

Comment: good , what is error message >?

Comment: no error message in it url is also passing but it is not inserting

Comment: post your stored procedure creation script

Answer (score 0):

you must have a column(if not add 1 with name url) in database let say url which also will be available(if not add a property with the name url) in Model class ip. You method dblayer.Add_data_pharma(ip) will do the rest.

> `ip.url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`

Comment: it is not inserted in the db,i want to pass anything in view

Comment: do you want to insert url in database? or just pass it on the view?

Comment: i want to  insert url in the database

Comment: you can use, viewbag/viewdata/tempdata: e.g: ViewBag.Url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri; in view you can get value like: string s = View.Url;

Comment: i want to insert it directly in view part i have not passed anythiung this my model 
 public string urlname { get; set; }

Comment: <div class="form-group">

                                                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="urlname" name="urlname">
                                                    </div> this my input field

Comment: Please answere me i feel diffcult in doing this

Comment: dblayer.Add_data_pharma(ip) it is not saving